# Laravel 5 link_to_* with icon/html

Tags: laravel-5

Anyone figured out how to put HTML inside $title parameter of link_to_* helper functions?

I've been googling around and found some topics about it directly on [laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/09-25-2014-how-to-get-font-awesome-icons-to-show-up-when-using-link-to-route) but there are only suggestions:

1. make your own helper (tried but in the end I use link_to_* or `App::make('html')->linkRoute(...);` example [helpers](http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/helper-link-functions-with-font-awesome-icons).
2. generate links inside views and use URL facade
3. Use HTML facade to encode links in views (I think this is not secure, do not know why just feels like it is wrong).

To make myself clear I am asking **how to make 1. suggestion work?** (I tried helpers but result is the same when using L5 helper `link_to_route('some.route', 'This is title with icon <i class="icon"></i>');` and helper that I made (code below). Where `$icon = '<i class="some-icon"></i>';`

```
if ( ! function_exists('link_to_route_icon'))
{

    function link_to_route_icon($name, $title = null, $icon = null,  $parameters = array(), $attributes = array())
    {
        return app('html')->linkRoute($name, $title . $icon, $parameters, $attributes);
    } 
}
```

both (my own helper or L5 helper) output the same result:

- visible in browser: `name<i class="fa-sort-alpha-asc"></i>`
- html code: `<a href="http://acme.dev/dashboard/users?order=desc&amp;sort=name">name&lt;i class="fa-sort-alpha-asc"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</a>`

## Solution

```
if ( ! function_exists('link_to_route_icon'))
{

    function link_to_route_icon($name, $title = null, $icon = null, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array())
    {
        $url = route($name, $parameters);

        return '<a href="' . $url . '"' . app('html')->attributes($attributes) . '>' . htmlentities($title) . ' ' . $icon . '</a>';
    }
}
```

---

Please note when using L5 and you want to use your own helper.php, you have to load it in composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
},
"files": [
    "app/Helpers.php"
]
```

Comment: Those are pretty much the options you have. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Frankly all the suggestions are "wrong", I simply want to send HTML (icon in my case) to the method that creates everything for me. 1. suggestion DOES NOT WORK and I want to make it work that is my question. 2. suggestion is useless because in view there is going to be too much repetitive code. 3. suggestion reason is in the brackets. @lukasgeiter see my edit, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `linkRoute` method which eventually calls `htmlentities` on the passed title string. You have to build the HTML yourself to make it work. Here's a generic example (feel free to optimize it more for the purpose of generating icon links)

```php
function link_to_route_html($name, $html, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array())
{
    $url = route($name, $parameters);
    return '<a href="'.$url.'"'.app('html')->attributes($attributes).'>'.$html.'</a>';
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
link_to_route_html('some.route', 'This is title with icon <i class="icon"></i>');
```

Comment: The (latest) link_to() helper also excepts $secure as 4th parameter & $escape as 5th.  Setting escape to false I was able to put html in as title.